# Export MYSQL table to CSV. Query doesn't work

Tags: mysql, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export some field of a table into a csv file...
The query that I'm using is

```
SELECT "field1", "field1", "field3"
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM mytable
INTO OUTFILE "/Users/davide/Documents/file.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

But mysql returns

```
ERROR 1222 (21000): The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

The table has 2 fields more but I don' t think this is the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Having two more fields IS a problem. The same number of columns in the CSV has to match the table you're importing into.

Comment: Why don't you think it's a problem if the table has 5 columns but you UNION with a query that has 3 columns? This is an error in the standard definition of UNION and in every SQL implementation. And it's literally what the error message tells you.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `SELECT *`, list the specific columns that you want to put into the CSV. `SELECT *` means to return all the columns in the table.

```
SELECT "field1", "field1", "field3"
UNION ALL
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM mytable
INTO OUTFILE "/Users/davide/Documents/file.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you use `UNION` statement, you have to make sure both `SELECT`s statements have the same number of columns

If you need to fill an "empty" space, you can use `NULL`, for example

```
SELECT "field1", "field1", "field3", NULL, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM mytable
INTO OUTFILE "/Users/davide/Documents/file.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: The query works, however all the fields are into the csv, not the selected only

Comment: Your second select has a `*` so it selects all of them,  you need to specify what you want the output to look like, it would help with sample input also